# applying and assigning with lambda and struggling to resolve

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a function definition to retrieve maximum value in a column

```
def highestHigh(date1,ticker,allp_df):
    currDate= datetime.datetime.now().date()
    allpm_df = allp_df.loc[((allp_df['Ticker']==ticker)&(allp_df['date']>=date1)&(allp_df['date']<=currDate)),'high']
    return allpm_df.max()
```

the date1 and ticker comes from a dataframe (init_df) and i am trying to populate a new column "HighestHigh" in the same dataframe and i tried three option below with different errors:

```
init_df=init_df.assign(HighestHigh= lambda x : highestHigh(x['DateIdentified'],x['Ticker'],allprice_df))
```

and got the error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

```
init_df.HighestHigh=init_df.HighestHigh.apply(lambda x: highestHigh(x['DateIdentified'],x['Ticker'],allprice_df))
```

and got the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Lastly, i tried:

```
init_df.HighestHigh=init_df.HighestHigh.apply(lambda x: highestHigh(x['DateIdentified'],x['Ticker'],allprice_df), axis=1)
```

and got the error:

> TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

I guess I can iterate thru rows to solve this, but trying to do the calculations at once..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is `date1`. `date1` is not a scalar value like '2020-07-11' but the Series `allp_df['DateIdentified']`.

So `(allp_df['date']>=date1)` will raise an exception even if `init_df` contains only one row:

```
>>> allp_df['date'] >= pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01'))
...
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

# If init_df contains only 1 row, use squeeze
>>> allp_df['date'] >= pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')).squeeze()
0      False
1      False
2      False
3      False
...
```

Comment: in the code ```init_df.HighestHigh=init_df.HighestHigh.apply(lambda x: highestHigh(x['DateIdentified'],x['Ticker'],allprice_df))``` when we pass x['DateIdentified'] in the lambda function - isn't that supposed to be scalar? or What exactly is x there?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to code that works (below).

```
  init_df = init_df.assign(HighestHigh = lambda x: 
  highestHigh(x['DateIdentified'], x['Ticker'],' allprice_df))
```

```
     def highestHigh(date1,ticker,allp_df):
      if date1.size == ticker.size:
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['DateIdentified','Ticker'])
        temp_df['DateIdentified'] = date1
        temp_df['Ticker'] = ticker
    else:
        print("dates and tickers size mismatching")
        sys.exit(1)
    counter = itertools.count(0)
    high_list = [getHigh(x,y,allp_df, next(counter)) for x, y in zip(temp_df['DateIdentified'],temp_df['Ticker'])]
    return high_list
```

```
def getHigh(dateidentified,ticker,allp_df, count):
     print("trade %s" % count)
    currDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    allpm_df = allp_df.loc[((allp_df['Ticker']==ticker)&(allp_df['date']>dateidentified)&(allp_df['date']<=currDate)),['high','date']]
    hh = allpm_df.iloc[:,0].max()
    hd = allpm_df.loc[(allpm_df['high']==hh),'date']
    hh = round(hh,2)
    h_list  = [hh,hd]
    return h_list
```

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask questions.